# DataGrid View Checkbox not being picked up as checked

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a datagridview with checkboxes in column index 12. There is a button on a toolsstrip which needs to iterate these checked rows and remove the items.

The code I have is not detecting that the cell is checked (bChecked variable is always false), its value when debugging is false.

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    DataGridViewCheckBoxCell oCell = row.Cells[12] as DataGridViewCheckBoxCell;
    bool bChecked = (null != oCell && null != oCell.Value && true == (bool)oCell.Value);

    if (bChecked == true)
    {
        //Do something
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Is it possible that your index(12) are wrong and you reading some other column. If columns of `DataGridView` a predefined, than better to use a variable of column like  `row.Cells[this.dgvCheckBoxColumn.Name]` Sorry I always fill bad when see a hardcoded values :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aren't you better off using the CellValueChanged event of the DataGridViewCheckBoxCell?
This event is raised every time the checkboxcell's value is changed.

See [DataGridViewCell.Value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.value.aspx) under the remarks section.

Subscribing to the event would give you a surefire way to detect if the cell is checked.